# magento 2 development with docker

Tags: magento2, docker

We are 2 developers using Linux,1 designer using Windows.

We have 3 environments
(develop-virtual,test-virtual in one server).

And live-its in different server.

We are using git with 3 branches: master, develop, test in gitlab.

we will pull develop branch in developing virtual server, test branch in the test server.
and master branch in live server.

Now I'm trying to use docker with git.
https://github.com/mageinferno/magento2-docker-compose

I have cloned above repo in my local Linux system and installed Docker.
also, i have setup Magento 2.
so now I can browse magento2 site also I can edit files from my system.
up to this point, everything is OK.

Now my query is:
How to commit my code, and how to use Docker in another developer, designer,3 environments?

I don't find proper use cases here.
one advantage I can find I can configure almost live system config in my local system.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience
You should create private repository in github or bitbucket for store all code. You can management all pull/push code by git. Bitbucket is free (good plus) for private repository.
For communication between developers you can use Trello , Slack, Skype..

For deployment you can use `DockerHub` (cloud docker images) for manager all your images you can build from local and push to hub, Or pull public images from docker community

Manager configuration and automation build you can take a look at Ansible

Production Server
-- docker-compose for production

Dev Server
-- configiuration 
-- stagging area 
-- test area 
-- src 
-- -- dev1 
 
-- -- dev2 
-- -- designer

Each user will have same docker-compose file configuration

Btw this topic quite large and seem not related much with magento